# remember_me_ttl not working in expression engine 2

Tags: php, expressionengine

I am using ee2 and also new in expression engine and wants to auto logout user after few time automatically if user is not doing anything on website.

To do this i have set below in "system/expressionengine/config/remember.php" file :

```
$config['remember_me_ttl'] = 60;
```

In above code i have set 1 minute time. After one minute i refresh the page but the user was still logged in. I also tried with closing browser but the user remains logged in.

Please let me know if i need to do some more changes for the same.

Answer (score 0):

in /system/expressionengine/config/session.php
You need to edit the line :

```
$config['sess_expiration'] = 60;
```

Comment: I do same thing and refresh page after 5 minutes but still i was logged in.

Comment: in system/expressionengine/libraries/Session.php change the line
public $user_session_len = 60;

Comment: This is not a good way to change in library file. Don't we have any logic by which we can do it without changing in core file ?

Comment: i agree, but it's really weird my first answer didn't solve the problem. Maybe your config contains some conflict. Try to play with 
$config['user_session_ttl'] = 60;
in your config/config.php